The SFTP server connection fails from the Lambda function, while it works without issues from the ECS instance [ssh2-sftp-client]
Node: 16
ssh2-sftp-client: 9
Connecting using username&password
Sample code
const Client = require('ssh2-sftp-client');
module.exports = class SFTPClient {
  #sftpClient;
  constructor() {
    this.#sftpClient = new Client();
  }
  async connect(options) {
    try {
      return this.#sftpClient.connect(options); // options = {host,port,username,password}
    } catch (err) {
      return null;
    }
  }
}

The connection was initially functioning properly, but it now fails on the lambda function, while the ECS instances continue to work fine.
here are the detailed logs from the Lambda
2024-10-29T21:37:39.289Z    b2a4f522-527d-4bbe-ae4f-116600d2bd76    INFO Debug:  CLIENT[sftp]: ssh2-sftp-client Version: 9.0.4  
{
    "node": "16.20.2",
    "v8": "9.4.146.26-node.26",
    "uv": "1.43.0",
    "zlib": "1.2.11",
    "brotli": "1.0.9",
    "ares": "1.19.1",
    "modules": "93",
    "nghttp2": "1.47.0",
    "napi": "8",
    "llhttp": "6.0.11",
    "openssl": "1.1.1v+quic",
    "cldr": "41.0",
    "icu": "71.1",
    "tz": "2022f",
    "unicode": "14.0",
    "ngtcp2": "0.8.1",
    "nghttp3": "0.7.0"
}

2024-10-29T21:37:39.290Z    b2a4f522-527d-4bbe-ae4f-116600d2bd76    INFO Debug:  CLIENT[sftp]: connect: Connect attempt 1
2024-10-29T21:37:39.293Z    b2a4f522-527d-4bbe-ae4f-116600d2bd76    INFO Debug:  Custom crypto binding not available
2024-10-29T21:37:39.771Z    b2a4f522-527d-4bbe-ae4f-116600d2bd76    INFO Debug:  Verifying signature ...
2024-10-29T21:37:39.772Z    b2a4f522-527d-4bbe-ae4f-116600d2bd76    INFO Debug:  Verified signature
2024-10-29T21:37:39.773Z    b2a4f522-527d-4bbe-ae4f-116600d2bd76    INFO Debug:  Handshake completed
2024-10-29T21:37:39.773Z    b2a4f522-527d-4bbe-ae4f-116600d2bd76    INFO    #sftpClient event handshake:  
{
    "kex": "ecdh-sha2-nistp256",
    "serverHostKey": "ssh-ed25519",
    "cs": {
        "cipher": "aes128-gcm@openssh.com",
        "mac": "",
        "compress": "none",
        "lang": ""
    },
    "sc": {
        "cipher": "aes128-gcm@openssh.com",
        "mac": "",
        "compress": "none",
        "lang": ""
    }
}

2024-10-29T21:37:39.898Z    b2a4f522-527d-4bbe-ae4f-116600d2bd76    INFO Debug:  Outbound: Sending USERAUTH_REQUEST (none)
2024-10-29T21:37:40.086Z    b2a4f522-527d-4bbe-ae4f-116600d2bd76    INFO Debug:  Socket error: read ECONNRESET
2024-10-29T21:37:40.087Z    b2a4f522-527d-4bbe-ae4f-116600d2bd76    INFO    #sftpClient event error:  Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20) {
  errno: -104,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read',
  level: 'client-socket'
}


We also tried using Node v20 and ssh2 v1.16.0, but it failed as well.


I see ssh2-sftp likes to test on specific node versions, try again with the following config:
ssh2 version 9.0.4
node version 16.17.2

Don't think it's a version-related issue because the same code works fine on AWS ECS instances.
We also tried using Node v20 and ssh2 v1.16.0, but it failed as well.

You mention it did work fine then stopped, try stress test the EC2 version and see if it eventually crashes the same way, I think you're running into too many TCP reconnect requests when the sftp server wants you to be persistent

See ssh2-sftp's HTTPAgent and HTTPSAgent for keepalive settings - or somewhere in AWS on the lambda setup screens
